# Delete query by joining two tables in a cost effective way

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have to delete a data from certain table, so i am using the following query:

```
delete from table_a 
where objectname in 
    (Select object_name from table_b where resolved='Y');
```

Now the `Select object_name from table_b where resolved='Y'` query will return more than 4 million records and hence will take a lot of time to execute. I am trying to write it in a more cost efficient way.

```
DELETE FROM table_a 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table_b WHERE object_name= objectname AND RESOLVED = ‘Y’ )
AND ROWNUM < 10000;
```

But there seems to be error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character 00911. 00000 - "invalid character" *Cause: identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than letters and numbers. $#_ are also allowed after the first character. Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain any character other than a doublequote. Alternative quotes (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as delimiters. For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language Reference Manual.

Please help!

Comment: *"seems to be erroring"* What error exactly do you get?

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.

Comment: Probably due to the funny quotes: `‘Y’`. Try with `'Y'` as in the first example.

Comment: Yes that seems to work, but the cost of the original query and the new query is exactly same. Is there a better way to write this delete query.

Comment: The query (both actually) seems fine to me but I'd prefer the `EXISTS` version over `IN`. It would help if you included the design of `table_b`, with the existing indexes (even better, of both tables).

Comment: For MySQL you can try using a JOIN instead of IN or EXISTS. MySQL is sometimes stupid with those...

Comment: I am using oracle, and can you please help me on how do i write a join query for delete in this case. Sorry i am very new to oracle and hence the doubt.

Comment: DELETE FROM Table A WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT object_name FROM table B WHERE object_name= objectname AND RESOLVED = 'Y' ) AND ROWNUM < 10000; I have to delete over 4 million records in table A, so every time i run this query it will restrict my result set to deleting 10K records. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

- a primary key on table_a
- a foreign key on table_b that references table_a and that is set to ON DELETE CASCADE or ON DELETE SET NULL

you can use an inline view for this:

```
create table table_a as (select distinct object_name from all_objects);
alter table table_a add constraint pk_a primary key (object_name);

create table table_b as (
  select 
    distinct object_name, 
    (case when object_name like 'A%' then 'Y' else 'N' end)   as resolved
    from table_a);    
alter table table_b add constraint fk_b_a foreign key (object_name) 
  references table_a(object_name) on delete cascade;

delete from (
  select b.resolved 
  from table_a a 
  join table_b b on a.object_name = b.object_name)
where resolved = 'Y';
```

but honestly, the EXISTS / IN approach is much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: DELETE FROM Table A
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT object_name FROM table B WHERE object_name= objectname AND RESOLVED = 'Y' )
AND ROWNUM < 10000;

I have to delete over 4 million records in table A, so every time i run this query it will restrict my result set to deleting 10K records. Is that correct?